# Is it possible to modify a K8s resource automatically?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**Problem:**

- In my helm chart `A` there is a requirement for an other chart `B`
- Chart `B` will create a K8s resource (let it be a service for now: `SVC_A`) at an unpredictable time
- I need to add something (a label, other port..etc) to `SVC_A`
- Chart `B` is badly written and doesn't expose anything about this `SVC_A` up to it's
  `Values.yaml`, everything is hardcoded

**What I can do:**

- Modify the `SVC_A` by hand with `kubectl patch` or `kubectl edit`
- Using an other pod which uses the kubernetes API and monitor and modify the given `SVC_A` automatically

**Question:**
How can I do it in an automatic way without a separate pod?
Do Helm or Kubernetes has some build in feature for this?

Comment: What's the thing you need to modify; how do you figure out its value?  Is the name, port number, _etc._ constructed in a consistent way?  Can you make the example a little more concrete, maybe with some sample YAML?

Comment: @David Maze
Name is consistent lets say NAME_A and I need to add a new port for example.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the software applications packed and installed with helm, then customization to any of dependent helm charts is possible only if helm templates' construct allows that. Unless the variants (e.g. different Port types) are not templated, there is no option to customize these resources with helm.

**Possible workaround:**

Use `helm teplate` command to generate only manifest files and then modify them on fly with:

- `kustomize`
- `kubectl patch`
- `kubectl create --overwrite`